# How do I set the rpath for C++ with Bazel on OS X

Tags: c++, macos, rpath, bazel

I have tried adding the following to my `BUILD` file:

```
linkopts = ["-Wl,-rpath path/to/add"],
```

But when I check the executable with

```
otool -L path/to/executable
```

It does not include `path/to/add`.  How can I change the rpath in the executable using bazel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that -Wl,-rpath is not really supported on OS X, we have to wrap the clang compiler with a [shell script that does the conversion](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/osx_cc_wrapper.sh). This shell script find the rpath specification and replace it with a call to install_name_tool.

I haven't found a way to handle multiple rpath so far for Mach-O binaries.